# first and last record in one query

Tags: postgresql, order-by, distinct

i want to select first and last score from such data

```
WITH t AS (
SELECT 1 user_id, '2019-05-15'::date AS created_at, 4 as score
UNION ALL
SELECT 1 user_id, '2019-05-13'::date AS created_at, 12 as score
UNION ALL
SELECT 2 user_id, '2019-05-15'::date AS created_at, 7 as score
UNION ALL
SELECT 3 user_id, '2019-05-13'::date AS created_at, 6 as score
),
first_score AS (
    SELECT DISTINCT ON (user_id)
        created_at, score, user_id
    FROM t
    ORDER BY user_id, created_at ASC
),
last_score AS (
    SELECT DISTINCT ON (user_id)
        created_at, score, user_id
    FROM t
    ORDER BY user_id, created_at DESC
)

select
    md5(u.user_id::varchar) user_id,
    u.created_at signup_date,
    fhs.created_at first_score_created_at,
    fhs.score first_score,
    lhs.created_at last_score_created_at,
    lhs.score last_score
from t as u 
    INNER JOIN first_score fhs ON fhs.user_id = u.user_id
    INNER JOIN last_score lhs ON lhs.user_id = u.user_id;
```

my question: is exists a way to make one subquery to join the first_score and last_score in single query?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
WITH t AS (
SELECT 1 user_id, '2019-05-15'::date AS created_at, 4 as score
UNION ALL
SELECT 1 user_id, '2019-05-13'::date AS created_at, 12 as score
UNION ALL
SELECT 2 user_id, '2019-05-15'::date AS created_at, 7 as score
UNION ALL
SELECT 3 user_id, '2019-05-13'::date AS created_at, 6 as score
)
SELECT
    md5(user_id::varchar) user_id,
    created_at signup_date,
    MIN(created_at) OVER (PARTITION BY user_id) first_score_created_at,
    FIRST_VALUE(score) OVER (PARTITION BY user_id ORDER BY created_at ASC) first_score,
    MAX(created_at) OVER (PARTITION BY user_id) last_score_created_at,
    FIRST_VALUE(score) OVER (PARTITION BY user_id ORDER BY created_at DESC) last_score
FROM t
```

Comment: PS. You think that you can use `LAST_VALUE(score) .. last_score` for to use the same window as for `first_score`? Sorry, but it can give wrong result (seems to be a bug)...

Comment: It's no bug, it's to do with the default window frame. Basically, when you specify `ORDER BY`, the frame ends at the current row (it's slightly more complicated than that but will do for this scenario), unless you explicitly specify it to be something else. If you set the frame as `ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND UNBOUNDED FOLLOWING` to cover the entire partition, you can use `LAST_VALUE` just fine. See [here](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-expressions.html#SYNTAX-WINDOW-FUNCTIONS) for more details.

Comment: @AndriyM Thanks. In my queries I always set rows/range, so I have no seen this problem... and here I tried to save bytes...